# IText: what is behinde getAscentPoint(), what shall I expect while using a custom font?

Tags: fonts, itext

I use myfont.otf font to create a BaseFont, and retrieving my other application fonts from this basefont.

When I call

```
myfont.getBaseFont().getAscentPoint("Blabla",myfont.getSize());
```

I get back a "0". What is the reason? I have allready read the links [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/using-fonts)  and [that](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11).

Answer (score 1):

`getAscentPoint` is implemented like this:

```
public float getAscentPoint(String text, float fontSize)
{
    return getAscent(text) * 0.001f * fontSize;
}
```

and `getAscent` like this:

```
public int getAscent(String text) {
    int max = 0;
    char chars[] = text.toCharArray();
    for (int k = 0; k < chars.length; ++k) {
        int bbox[] = getCharBBox(chars[k]);
        if (bbox != null && bbox[3] > max)
            max = bbox[3];
    }
    return max;
}
```

If you *get back a "0"*, therefore, this may be caused by

- your `fontSize` parameter in your `getAscentPoint` call being 0 or
- none of the characters in "Blabla" having a boundary box with an upper **y** coordinate greater 0.

As I don't have "myfont.otf" and don't know how `myfont` exactly is created, I cannot tell which one it is in your case.